# Get data about the position of our sun through a function. How?

Tags: javascript, function

I am using [mourner/suncalc](https://github.com/mourner/suncalc) to get information about our sun. I want to get all the times where the position of our sun will be, using `SunCalc.getTimes()`, but to prevent using "miles long" variables, I want to call each data through a function.

I am thinking about something like this:

```
function sun_times(string) {
    var sun_times = SunCalc.getTimes(new Date(), 54.528486, -7.569268);
    return (sun_times.string.getHours().toString() < 10 ? '0' + sun_times.string.getHours().toString() : sun_times.string.getHours().toString());
}

console.log(sun_times('dawn'));
```

This example returns (as expected) `TypeError: sun_times.string is undefined`.

Instead of entering `sun_times.dawn.getHours().toString() + ':' + sun_times.dawn.getMinutes().toString()` for every time at dawn, dusk, golden hour, nadir, nautical dawn, and so on, I just want to enter the function and then the data I want to print out, for an example `sun_times('dawn')`.

How can I accomplish this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JavaScript object works like a dictionary structure. We use the `[]` indexing operator to access properties only known at runtime. It's like array access, but with strings instead of numbers.

```
function sun_times(string) {
    var sun_times = SunCalc.getTimes(new Date(), 54.528486, -7.569268);
    return (sun_times[string].getHours().toString() < 10 ? '0' + sun_times[string].getHours().toString() : sun_times[string].getHours().toString());
}
```